# [iOS Objective C]Drag Bezier curve from a point on closed bezier curve path

Tags: uibezierpath, bezier, nsbezierpath

[Sample image for the requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa8Jd.png)I have drawn a closed path bezier curve using the UIBezier path code.Im able to find if touched point on screen is on the closed bezier path boundary or outside it.
Requirement:- I need to drag the point where user touched on the closed path bezier curve boundary and make the closed path bezier curve extend.

Refer:- 
The below question is same as mine but i could not find a solution from it.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53819/changing-a-bezier-curve-by-dragging-a-point-on-the-curve-itself-rather-than-a-co

It would be a great help if i could get the Objective C code or algorithm to do the above functionality.

Hi Fang, I have posted the image in my post which illustrates the requirement.
Currently i have only point A and point B which is from user touch and move finger. 
I need to calculate point C and D and remove the path CD so that it looks like the original curve is just expanded in the user finger movement direction.

Note:- I do all this when i get a closed curve.If not closed the user is able to draw free hand which im able to achieve.Currently using quad curve for my requirement.

Any help would be greatful.

Comment: The link in your post provides two different solutions. If you know the parameter associated with the point you are dragging, it is easier to go with Solution 1, which will compute the new position of a nearby control point. Otherwise, go with Solution 2, which is simply a Bezier curve interpolation.

Comment: As observed in the link the above it is not clear that solution is working.

Comment: Both solutions will work. Read them in details and post questions where you don't understand and I will try to explain.

Comment: I have the point touch by user on curve boundary.Now when user drags the curve to a new point in view, it should expand the curve along with user finger movement. The algorithm provided is not sufficient or lacks information that how can we achieve the functionality. Can you please help me provide the code or detail algo her.

Comment: I post a more detailed description about the "Solution 1" as answer. I did not elaborate on "Solution 2" for now because Solution 1 is preferable.

Comment: Is the bigger closed curve (showb in your picture) formed by multiple quadratic (or cubic) Bezier curves?  Also, why do you need to compute point C and point D?

Comment: Yes both the curves are drawn by multiple quad curves when user moves his touch on screen.I need to calculate C and D so that i can remove the segment CD and show user the updated curve with smaller curve joining with bigger curve on C and D.

Comment: Fang, could you please add me on skype(amit.dhawan86).I can show you the demo of my requirement which would help understand the problem in detail.I would be really thankful if you can add me.

Comment: Point C and D can simply be the end points of the quadratic Bezier segment where point A resides. Once you figure out which quadratic Bezier segment the point A resides, all the formula in my answer will become applicable. Sorry, I have not used Skype for a long long time.

Comment: Ahh...i think thats the main problem.Do you know any math formula to get the nearby points on curve segment (bezier path)?

Comment: What is "nearby points" on curve segment?

Comment: it should be the points which make the curve smooth i.e when i draw the curve with B as control point.They are the start and end points to be exact.

Comment: Still have no idea what you are talking about. Point B is the new location of point A, which you want the Bezier curve to pass thru, isn't it? How come it becomes a control point?

Comment: Yes the new point will be B it would be control point as the curve will be drawn around it.Could you tell in terms of image what would be the Control Point,Start Point and end point.?

Comment: Point B is a control point of the new path? This is not the same as shown in the picture. Also, if point B is a control point, then where would point A be moved to?  I think you are deviating from your original post gradually to an extent that I won't be able to provide a coherent answer. It is better that you rethink about what you really want to do and post a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a quadratic Bezier curve C(t) and the point A you would like to drag is at parameter t0, then we have

```
 A=C(t0)=(1-t0)^2*P0+2t0(1-t0)*P1+t0^2*P2        (1)
```

Now, you drag the point A to B, so we have

```
 B=D(t0)=(1-t0)^2*Q0+2t0(1-t0)*Q1+t0^2*Q2        (2)
```

Since we would like C(t) and D(t) to share the same end point, so we have P0=Q0 and P2=Q2. Then, from equations (1) and (2), we have

```
 B-A = 2t0(1-t0)(Q1-P1), or
 Q1 = (B-A)/(2t0(1-t0)) + P1
```

Similarly, if you have a cubic Bezier curve, we will have

```
 A=C(t0)=(1-t0)^3*P0+3t0(1-t0)^2*P1+3t0^2(1-t0)*P2+t0^3*P3        (3)
 B=D(t0)=(1-t0)^3*Q0+3t0(1-t0)^2*Q1+3t0^2(1-t0)*Q2+t0^3*Q3        (4)
```

Again, combining (3) and (4) and keeping the same end points P0=Q0 and P3=Q3 will result in

```
  B-A = 3t0(1-t0)^2*(Q1-P1)+3t0^2(1-t0)*(Q2-P2),
```

and we have

```
  Q1= w(B-A)/(3t0(1-t0)^2) + P1, and
  Q2= (1-w)(B-A)/(3t0^2(1-t0)) + P2
```

where w is just a weighting value between [0,1].

As you can see that for a cubic Bezier curve, you really have infinite solutions for moving P1 and P2 so that the point C(t0) is moved from point A to point B. You can choose to move only P1 or P2 (by setting w to 0.0 or 1.0) or moving both of them (by setting w to any value between 0.0 and 1.0). More complex algorithm will decide the value of w by minimizing the integrated difference between C(t) and D(t) but I guess we don't need to go there.

Above is just a more detailed description about the "Solution 1" mentioned in the link in your post. I would recommend you to go with this approach (when compared to the Solution 2). If you do have a quadratic or cubic Bezier curve, finding the parameter t0 associated with a point at C(t0) is just finding the root of degree 2 or 3 polynomial, which should not be difficult.

Comment: Hi fang,Thanks for your solution.While i was solving it on paper i discovered the equation Q1 = (B-A)/(2t0(1-t0)) + P1 has P1 and Q1 as 2 unknown variables. Please guide how can i solve this equation given i have A,B and t0.  Same applies for cubic curve too   Q2= (1-w)(B-A)/(3t0^2(1-t0)) + P2.Also i suppose the t will also change as the user moves from point A to point B? If possible please provide eqation to get t value for touched points.

Comment: Also please check my edited question above which shows the requirement of calculation the start and end points (C & D) by which the quad will be drawn.

Comment: P1 (or P1 and P2 for the cubic case) is the control point of your original Bezier curve, which should be known to you.  If for some reason, you don't have P1 but do have its paramater t0, you still can obtain P1 from equation (1).

Comment: I suppose in above case the curve will not share common end points as C and D are different in equation u said P0=Q0 and P2=Q2 will not hold true in this case.